# How to change Pagination in datatables after row grouping

Tags: datatables

I want the Pagination in datatables to be applied for the groups and not on the total no of rows.How to do that.

Comment: If you want the pagination to work on row groups, not rows, then the short answer is : "That is not possible".  I have a hard time to imagine how this should be accomplished - it would involve dynamic pagelength and a different approach to sorting.

Comment: @davidkonrad Ok.thanks.then i am thinking to remove row grouping and use Child rows to achieve that.Correct me if i am wrong